# iOS image picker library not displaying image preview

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have been struggling with this bug for a while. It is really weird (as has been working fine in other projects). For some reason the image picker does not display the thumbnails, although the images are selectable a blank thumbnail is displayed.

Things we have already try without success:

- Display this picker the first time when our app runs on the app delegate to avoid weird interactions
- Use external libraries to get the images, they all present the same issue.
- Create a new empty project with the same source code (only the part to display the picker)(in that case works fine)

Obviously is something related to our project setup or some weird interaction with a library... but no clue. Anyone?

[image]

Comment: I think this was due to memory leak

Comment: post ur source code used to show the image picker

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found it, was a side effect of declaring a NSDictionary category to handle nil json values. Probably the library uses internally NSDictionary and was not liking our category.